# How to align angular2/4 material label icons to the right on each tab?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following:

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="MyLabel">
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
      MyLabel <md-icon>thumb_down</md-icon>
    </ng-template>    
    Content
   </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

How can I adjust the position of the thumb_down icon to be lined up properly with "MyLabel"? Right now it appears to be slightly above it. Applying a style="line-height:40px;" to md-icon does not work.

Comment: If its slightly above in the same line, then apply `top` to `<md-icon>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your need to add this class for change position.

```
/deep/.mat-tab-label, /deep/.mat-tab-label-active{
  line-height: 30px!important;
}
```

**make sure you use scss (SASS) instead of css.**
if you used css then change it to scss file instead css. because deep only work with scss (SASS) file